# JSFL Command Split Textfield into Words - Flash Array Order error

Tags: actionscript-3, split, flash-cs5, textfield, jsfl

This command is supposed to take a selected textfield in Flash and cut it up into different groups based on the words or spaces in the textfield. The command is mixing up the order of the words. (In the code below I took out the part that distributes the groups to different layers.)

If I type the words "Test of the command", and run the command, it reverses the character count and cuts up the textfield from the back to the front.

For example, the first word "**TEST**" has four letters. The error is that it will start counting from the end of the textfield at the "d" at the end of word "**command**".

So the result is cutting up "**mand**" when it should be cutting up "TEST", and so on. If you count from the back to the front, you can see that the splitting corresponds to the correct number of letters, but its reversed...

My first instinct was to try to reverse the order of one of the arrays with .reverse(). It didn't work though.

I am working with Flash CS 5.5, AS3. Please help!

Here is a pic of what I am talking about...

[image]

```
var doc = fl.getDocumentDOM();

var mystring = doc.getTextString();


var numberOfWords = mystring.split(" ").length;
var wordArray = new Array();
for (var k = 0; k < numberOfWords; k++){
    wordArray[k] = new Array();
}

cntrNew = i = j = 0;
for (var ctr = 0; ctr < mystring.length; ctr++){
    if (mystring.charAt(ctr) == " "){
        i++;
    }
    else{
        wordArray[i].push(cntrNew);
        cntrNew++;
    }
}

doc.breakApart();
var selectionArray = new Array();
var tempArray = new Array();
var finalArray = new Array();

selectionArray = doc.selection;
doc.selectNone();

for (var i in wordArray){
    for (var k = 0; k < wordArray[i].length; k++){
        fl.trace(wordArray[i][k]);
        //wordArray.reverse();
        tempArray[k] = selectionArray[wordArray[i][k]];
     }
    fl.trace("break");

    doc.selection = tempArray;
    doc.group();
    finalArray[i] = doc.selection;
    doc.selectNone();
 }
```

Comment: you're just trying to split the string at the space??

Answer (score 2):

maybe this will help. I simplified your process a little bit. I tested in an AS3 project with a text field on the stage called 'txt'

```
var mystring:String = txt.text;
var words:Array     = mystring.split(" ");

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    for (var k = 0; k < words[i].length; k++)
    {
        trace("letter:",words[i].charAt(k));
    }
    trace("-");
}
```

It outputs:

```
letter: t
letter: e
letter: s
letter: t
-
letter: o
letter: f
-
letter: t
letter: h
letter: e
-
letter: c
letter: o
letter: m
letter: m
letter: a
letter: n
letter: d
letter: s
-
```

Comment: Ok, so how would I break those words apart into separate movieclips?

Would I have to add those words[i].charAt(k)) to another array and then have that be selected or broken apart and grouped?

Comment: hey, so I got it to work with it outputting the correct order... but for some reason the outcome is still the same...

Comment: never mind I figured out that I coudl just reverse the for loop for the counter

Instead of this
for (var ctr = 0; ctr < mystring.length; ctr++)

Just do a reversed counter starting at mystring.length